# Comparing values of a vector with the first one returns NA values

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to compare the i+1 elements of a vector with the first element of the vector itself.

I have the following dataframe:

```
snsr_dt snsr_ts value
2009-05-25  2009-05-25 08:00    0
2012-07-08  2012-07-08 08:00    96
2014-01-27  2014-01-27 08:00    0
2015-02-15  2015-02-15 08:00    298
2015-10-10  2015-10-10 08:00    260
2017-04-21  2017-04-21 08:00    402
```

I have tried the following approach:

```
test<-c()
for (i in nrow(mydataframe)){
    test[i]=dataframe[i,3]-dataframe[1,3]
}
```

I am getting the following results:

```
[1]  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 402
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Typo in `for` loop, `for (i in 1:nrow(mydataframe))`

Comment: assuming `value` is the column vector you want to compare: `mydataframe$value - mydataframe$value[1]`

Answer (score 0):

We don't need a loop for this as the operation is vectorized

```
test <- mydataframe[,3] - mydataframe[,3][1]
```

---

Regarding the loop issue, it is only looping through one row i.e. the last row (`nrow`) of the dataset.  Instead, it can be `seq_len(nrow(mydataframe))`